# Enhanced for loop to stream

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming, java-stream

I have been trying to use Stream instead of the enhanced for loop but I cannot incorporate correctly the if statements. Any help would be much appreciated

```
List<Donut> newDonuts = new ArrayList<>();
for (Donut currentElement : availableDonuts) {
    if (!alreadyPickedDonuts.contains(currentElement)) {
        newDonuts.add(currentElement);
        if (newDonuts.size() == extraDonutsRequired) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
availableDonuts.stream()
            .filter(currentElement -> !alreadyPickedDonuts.contains(currentElement))
            .limit(extraDonutsRequired)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: This version is safer because it correctly handles the `extraDonutsRequired == 0` case

Comment: True. Though in my original code, this is part of a method that will never be called if extraDonutsRequired == 0.